# multiple user prompts node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to query the user twice (more than once in general), but everything gets printed out together and the first response get processed by both functions. I believe this has to do with the asynchronous nature of node.js. Can you please point me towards module that would take care of this for me or an implementation  in prompt module? Thank you.

```js
var prompt = require('prompt');
prompt.start();
console.log("Enter a number: ");
prompt.get(['number'], function(err, result) {
  if (!isNaN(result.number)) {
    console.log("You entered a number.");
  } else {
    console.log("You did not enter a number.");
  }
});


var prompt2 = require('prompt');
prompt2.start();
console.log("Enter a number again: ");
prompt2.get(['number1', 'number2'], function(err, result) {
  if (Number(result.number1) > Number(result.number2))
    console.log("The first input is bigger");
  else if (Number(result.number1) == Number(result.number2))
    console.log("Both inputs are equal");
  else
    console.log("The second input is bigger");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you actually need both prompt instances. I think you can achieve what you want with only one prompt and just calling `get` second time within the first `get`'s callback.

```js
  
var prompt = require('prompt');
  prompt.start();
  console.log("Enter a number: ");
  prompt.get(['number'], function(err, result) {
   if (!isNaN(result.number)) {
     console.log("You entered a number.");
   } else {
     console.log("You did not enter a number.");
   }

   console.log("Enter a number again: ");
   prompt.get(['number'], function(err, result) {
     if (result.number < 20)
       console.log("small");
     else if (result.number < 50)
       console.log("medium");
     else
       console.log("large");
   });
  });
```

Comment: Absolutely, your answer does solve my dilemma. I was wondering in general if I wanted to get two responses from the user at two separate times.